# how to access the id of any button on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button as such whose id I am not aware of

```
  <button id="" class="mybtn" type=""></button>
```

and now I want to get the id of this button on click

```
    ("//what to write here").click(){
      console.log($(this).id);//something like this i want
     }
```

but the problem with using class selector is that I have multiple buttons which so it will select all of them and not just the one which is clicked.

Comment: If you use `$('.mybtn').on('click', function() { console.log(this.id) })`, it will only log the ID of the button clicked

Comment: You could narrow your `css selector` to include your target button's parent, like `.container .wrapper .mybtn::nth-child(3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this. I commented the code for the syntax

```js
$("button.mybtn").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("id")); // return blank when no id
  console.log(this.id); // return undefined when no id
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button id="hello" class="mybtn" type="">Sample</button>
  <button id="hello1" class="mybtn" type="">Sample</button>
```

Comment: You can ensure you only target buttons with IDs via `"button.mybtn[id]"`

Answer (score 2):

The event handler below is attached to all buttons (elements) with the class `.btn` but since you can only click one button at a time, you will only see one `id` per click - the id of the button clicked:

```
$('.mybtn').on('click', function() {
    console.log( this.id );
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.mybtn').on('click', function() {
        console.log( this.id );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="id1" class="mybtn" type="">Button 1</button>
 <button id="id2" class="mybtn" type="">Button 2</button>
 <button id="id3" class="mybtn" type="">Button 3</button>
 <button id="id4" class="mybtn" type="">Button 4</button>
```